# Sitecore GEO IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, sitecore, intranet

I have an environment where a few Sitecore servers are behind a firewall & the reverse proxy in different AWS-VPCs (internet & intranet) with AWS Gateway. I need Geo-IP to be enabled and updated to the Sitecore host node for the device analytics dashboard (access via intranet or internet). Any possible suggestion? Thank you.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! Have you taken a [tour] and learn [ask]? I hope you did. Anyway is this question related in any way to programming or management/administrative stuff? By the [look of it](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/90/sitecore-experience-manager/set-up-sitecore-ip-geolocation.html), it seems more of CMS management stuff. Perhaps you should consult with Sitecore support for this one, really.

Answer (score 0):

Reverse proxies typically forward the IP address from the connecting client via an additional http header `X-Forwarded-For`. See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-For . You might need to enable this on AWS, I'm unfamiliar with their services.

However, also on the Sitecore end, you then need to enable *reading* of the header. This has been support for quite a while, and the documentations seems to have changed barely (if at all) since version 9.0:
https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/90/sitecore-experience-manager/set-up-sitecore-ip-geolocation.html

The interesting bits are at the bottom, though:

> When requests come from a reverse proxy server to your Sitecore instance that you want to track as the valid IP addresses of a client (not as the IP addresses of a proxy), use the following setting.
>
> - In Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.config change the Analytics.ForwardedRequestHttpHeader setting to the value: X-Forwarded-For